# Regular expression to compare the first n characters of a string array

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex

I am working on some auto complete example and i want only the words starting with the entered text.

EG:-if i type "al" then i want only first two as my results not the 3rd one

```
**Al**abama
**Al**aska
c**al**lifornia
```

Comment: How far did you come?

Comment: @Jongware done. both answers work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**If you want the FASTEST METHOD *(case insensitive)*:**

```
var options = ['Alabama', 'Alaska', 'California', 'New York'];

function compare (string, ar) {
    return ar.filter(function (a) {
        return a.toLowerCase().indexOf(string.toLowerCase())===0;
    });
}

var results = compare('AL', options);
console.log( results );
```

`results` is:

> ["Alabama", "Alaska"]

This works by going through all options, it checks if the begin with the string, if they do, it keeps them

---

**If you want REGEX:**

```
var options = ['Alabama', 'Alaska', 'California', 'New York'];

function compare (string, ar) { 
    return ar.filter(function (a) { 
        return (new RegExp("^(?:" + string + ")", "i")).test(a);
    }); 
}

var results = compare('AL', options);
console.log( results );
```

---

**If you want to test just ONE ITEM, do:**

```
function compare (a, b) { 
    return a.toLowerCase().indexOf(b.toLowerCase())===0 
}
```

> `compare('Al', 'Alabama');`     -->  **true**
>
> `compare('AL', 'Alabama');`     -->  **true**
>
> `compare('al', 'California');`  -->  **false**

Comment: i want case insensitive

Comment: @vihan1086: Mind indenting those lines properly? A single line function like that is unnecessarily hard to read.

Comment: what is 'ar' and 'a' in function call

Comment: @user1655222 `ar` is the array with options that the function gets. The first two functions take in an array, and return an array with the matched elements. The matched just two strings. `ar` is  the array with the options. We have to check each string to see if it matches, to do that, we use `.filter()`. In the `filter()` a is the current string that we are checking

Comment: @vihan1086: Your functions weren't filtering `ar`, but were filtering `options` instead. Fixed that for you...

Comment: object does not support test at 'a'

Comment: @vihan1086: That jsPerf has some string concatenation in the `indexOf` test that makes the `indexOf` significantly slower. After removing the dubious concatenation, [`indexOf` blows the regexes out of the water.](http://jsperf.com/regexp-indexof-perf/57) It's basically twice as fast.

Comment: Yea... I really don't see what all the extra fuzz is about in that regex there. [They're way overcomplicated, although it seems to make them faster](http://jsperf.com/regexp-indexof-perf/57)

Answer (score 2):

You don't need a regex for that. Just check if your search string is found at the first position of the string you're checking:

```
"Some string".indexOf("So") === 0;
```

If you want, you can make it case insensitive:

```
"Some string".toLowerCase().indexOf("So".toLowerCase()) == 0;
```

And wrap it in a funtion:

```
function startsWith(str, search){
     return str.toLowerCase().indexOf(search.toLowerCase()) == 0;
}
```